# jquery remove onclick event

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have a couple of buttons, but depending on what radio button is selected I want 1 of 2 things to happen. e.g

when buildings radio button is selected, and the button is clicked then shows all building but doesnt show parks.
similarly when parks radio button is selected, and the button is  clicked shows all parks but doesnt show buildings.

i want to remove the onclick event for the appropriate feature that is not required, i could do this with.

```
$('#youLinkID').attr('onclick','').unbind('click');
```

however this will remove **BOTH** onclick events.

Is there either a way to remove only 1 onclick event, perhaps by name, or a way to add back an onclick event by name?

EDIT:
so I used the help of Mark below and used namespaces, and came up with this:

```
$('#showOver').bind('click.buildOver', function(){ 
        $(this).unbind('click.parkOver')
    });
```

Doesn't work however, I know its calling it and working as it runs my test,

```
.css({"backgroundColor":"black","color":"white"})
```

It jsut doesn't seem to add the onclick event of buildOver() function

Comment: do u have 2 `click` events on the same control ?

Comment: why dont you use different ID for both the radio buttons and try removing the event  for specific radio button (based on ID) when not required and add when required .

Comment: Use namespaces seems the better option here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use namespaces to `unbind` a partiuclar click handler.

```
$("a").bind("click.pick1", function () {
    alert('pick 1');
    $(this).unbind("click.pick1");
}).bind("click.pick2", function () {
    alert('pick 2');
});
```

[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/j4PsN/1/)

Comment: use on and off events instead of deprecated bind and unbind events.deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wRuj5/)

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('hello');">I produce an alert via onclick</a>
<a href="#" onclick="alert('hello');">Me too</a>

<a href="#" onclick="$('a').removeAttr('onclick');">I remove them</a>
```

The trick is this code:

```
$('a').removeAttr('onclick');
```

[**REFERENCE**](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)